# Compare ip when implementing aggregate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting, compare, ip, aggregate

I want to get all user have the same ip , and sort them. But the query is seems just compare first 2 components of ip but not the whole string, example 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.3.2 and then query just compared 127.0 and return results.

```
const aggregateQuery: any = [
            { $match: conditions },
            {
                "$project":
                {
                    "ipAddress": 1,
                    "username": 1,
                    'email': 1,
                    'createdAt': 1,
                    'status': 1,
                    "insensitive": { "$toLower": "$ipAddress" },
                    "fullIpAddress": { "$substr": ["$ipAddress", 0, -1] }
                }
            },
            { $group: { _id: '$fullIpAddress', count: { $sum: 1 }, users: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
            { $match: { count: { $gte: 1 } } }, { $unwind: '$users' },
            { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$users' } },
            { $sort: { insensitive: 1 } }
        ]
```

I tried to use substr to compare it but it's still not work